# how to have a property list of dictionaries and how to append dictionary to that ? (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, property-list

How can i have a property list of dictionaries, and how can I append a new dictionary to the property list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property list is a storage format for data -- plists aren't directly useful, but requires that you read them into data structures that you can use like NSArray and NSDictionary. A simple way to read a property list into mutable containers is to use NSPropertyListSerialization's `+propertyListFromData:mutabilityOption:format:errorDescription:` and specify `NSPropertyListMutableContainers` for the mutability option.

Also, there's an [entire manual devoted to property lists](http://tinyurl.com/66n9885).